# Import error running pytest

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, pytest, nose

My testing framework is in the following format, and I am trying to call login.py from test_login.py.

```
testSuite
  \projects
      \project1
         \pageobjects
              \login.py
          \testcase
              \test_login.py (contains class 'LoginPage')
  \testframeworkcode\
```

In test_login.py, when I import in the following way, I get the following error.

```
     from projects.project1.pageobjects.login import LoginPage

     ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'projects'
```

After bit of search, I then used the following way, which then gives me the error below

```
    from ..pageobjects.login import LoginPage

    ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

Can someone please help what's causing these errors?

I am using Python3 and using pytest to execute my test cases and using pycharm IDE.

Edit:
Following commands works fine, without any errors, when I execute it within 'testsuite' folder as in the folder structure described above.

```
  python3 -c 'import projects.project1.pageobjects.login'
  python3 -c 'import projects.project1.pageobjects'
  python3 -c 'import projects.project1' 
  python3 -c 'import projects'
```

However, I get a ModuleNotFoundError when I use these imports and execute the testcases using pytest or nosetests.

I do have **init**.py files in all subfolders in projects directory. I get the same results even if I remove these **init**.py files.

Comment: Any `__init__.py` files in there to suggest that there is a package? Import only work with packages, see [Modules and packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html). To have pytest work properly, your package should be importable properly.

Comment: yes. I included __init__.py file under projects folder and it dint help,

Comment: That is not enough (and by the way, did you include the double underscores before and after the "init" part of the filename?). What is important is that, starting from an element in the "Python path" ([sys.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path)). If you wish to write `from projects.project1.pageobjects.login`, there must be `projects/__init__.py`, `projects/project1/__init__.py` and `projects/project1/pageobjects/__init__.py`. I left aside voluntarily more advanced settings.

Comment: Yes. I did put __init__.py (with double underscore before and after init) files in each subfolders under projects folder, but this did not help either. I still get the same error.

Comment: From within the directory `testSuite`, can you run without error: `python3 -c 'import projects.project1.pageobjects.login'`, `python3 -c 'import projects.project1.pageobjects'`, `python3 -c 'import projects.project1'` and `python3 -c 'import projects'`? Please update your post will the output of these commands.

Comment: Thanks for your time @PierredeBuyl Fortunately, all these commands works fine without any errors. I get a modulenotfounderror only when I use these import statement and run them using pytest or nosetest.
Updated this info in my post.

Comment: From what directory do you run the pytest command, and with what (if any) arguments?

Comment: The best practice is to extract tests from source code and put it into its own directory such as `tests`.